# Is drop shipping business halal?

Tags: halal-haram, business

Is [drop shipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_shipping) business halal?

People in a drop shipping business sell the product at a higher price than the original price.
Because, the product I am selling is not in my inventory and I not the actual seller. (according to the rule of Islam)

Comment: Because, the product I am selling is not in my inventory and I not the actual seller. (according to the rule of Islam)

Comment: Even though it is not in your inventory, do you own it or block a certain number of units for yourself? I have had vendors who allow me to sell their products on our platform and then directly ship the product. It helps reduce the shipping and inventory costs. But we don't sell it for a higher price. The price infact reduces due to a drop in my cost price.